# sql nested query explanation

Tags: mysql

I came across this SQL Query in a contest.

Table: **Employees**

```
+------+------+--------+--------+
| ID   | Name | Salary | Branch |
+------+------+--------+--------+
|    1 | e1   |  10000 | cse    |
|    2 | e2   |  20000 | ece    |
|    3 | e3   |  12000 | ece    |
|    4 | e4   |  25000 | eee    |
|    5 | e5   |  15000 | ece    |
+------+------+--------+--------+
```

**Query**:

```
select * from Employees as e1 where e1.Branch="ece" and (select count(*) from Employees as e2 where e2.Branch="ece" and e1.Salary > e2.Salary) >= 2;
```

The **output** that I got was:

```
+------+------+--------+--------+
| ID   | Name | Salary | Branch |
+------+------+--------+--------+
|    2 | e2   |  20000 | ece    |
+------+------+--------+--------+
```

I didn't understand why I got this output. I can guess that maybe *it's giving the **employee** with **max** **salary** who is from **branch** **ece***. Some explanation of the query would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an example for **[`Correlated Subquery`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery)** where inner and outer query executes simultaneously

```
select * from Employees as e1 
    where e1.Branch="ece" and 
       (
          select count(*) from Employees as e2 where 
                e2.Branch="ece" and e1.Salary > e2.Salary
       ) >= 2;`
```

For each row of outer query get compared in inner query and result of inner query used to get final result from outer query.